# How do I view the individual nodes constituting a scene?

Tags: godot

Once I save a tree of nodes as a custom scene, the entire tree is folded into a single node in the scene dock. Within the inspector dock, the scene's node is represented only by the original top-level node before creating the scene.
So e.g., if, following the beginner tutorial, I try to create the following hierarchy:

```
RigidBody2D
├── CollisionShape2D
└── Sprite
```

and then save my RigidBody2D node as a scene called "Ball", the scene dock only shows:

`BallN`

for every instance of the `Ball` scene, hiding the hierarchy encapsulated under the new scene node.

The inspector still reveals that Ball scenes are actually RigidBody2D nodes, but is there a way to reveal CollisionShape2D and Sprite as the child nodes Ball is composed of, preferably within the scene dock itself?

Aside from looking at the inspector dock to see whether the entire object hierarchy is shown, I tried searching online for the answer, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting, I coincidentally found the answer due to my own clumsiness with a laptop's touchpad: if you double click an instance of the custom scene in the viewport, a new scene viewport opens up and gains focus, which only consists of the double-clicked scene and includes its entire node hierarchy.

This viewport can be used to edit the scene. Changes to the scene have an effect of all its instances within other scenes as well.

EDIT: Looking around a bit more, I found that the equivalent action to the double-tap would be right-clicking an instance of the scene in the scene dock and selecting "Open in Editor" from the context menu.

Alternatively, each instance's node hierarchy can be made visible by checking the box "Editable Children" in the context menu, which, considering that the context menu belongs to a single instance only, I assume provides for per-instance editing.

EDIT: I'll wait to see if someone has a better answer, maybe with more details or better convenience, and will accept it instead of my own answer.